# Syntax error in simple OCaml function?

Tags: ocaml

*Code:*

```
let fifthElem intList: int List = 
     if List.length intList = 0  then 0
     else if List.length intList >= 5 then List.nth intList 4

let sortDescend intList: int List = 
    let acendList = List.sort intList in 
     List.rev acendList
```

*Error:*

```
Syntax error
```

It says there's a syntax error on the first line between "List" and "=".

When I try to do:

```
let fifthElem (intList: int List) =
```

It says:

```
Syntax error: type expected.
```

How can I fix this? I just want to give `intList` type `int List`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` is a module name. Type names can start only from lowercase letters. The correct type name is `int list` not `int List`.

Also, OCaml default style is to use underscores, instead of CamelCase (albeit of the name of the language :)). So we usually write `fifth_elem` instead of fifthElem`.